# Asp.Net IE Userterface alignment

Tags: asp.net

I am facing a problem in asp.net applications.

I have developed a ASP.Net application which was compatible for ie6 browser. When i run the same application in ie8, half of the User interface is not visible.

I had enabled the **Display intranet site in compatibility view**. and selected

**Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Browsing enables / disables auto-recovery.**

Even then still my dialog userinterface ui elements are misplacing. I am invoking this as 
model dialog from the main page using java script.

i need urgent help.

Comment: you need more than *urgent help*. you made a site compatible for IE6 only? wow! can't wait to see how it renders in webkit / firefox. i dont think anybody can help you without seeing the site

Comment: @naveen : i cannot disclose the site since it is corporate confidential...

Answer (score 0):

These are some pointers on how to fix the issue. You have to work with each of them.

1. The CSS differences in IE6, IE7, IE8 ( [Read this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/) )
2. Conditional CSS for IE ( [Read this](http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) )
3. Using **IETester** for checking browser compatibility ( [Read this](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) )

With these you should be able to fix your website.

P.S: Don't ever code for IE6, its loooooong dead! ignore it. ( See [this](http://www.ie6update.com/) and [this](http://www.ie6nomore.com/) )